# How to Fix PHP Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated. Dont working

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7.2

I upgraded from PHP 5.3 to 7.2 and am getting the following error on 2 lines of code. This is the end of plugin code.

Thanks for help.

> Error log: 16:20:58 GMT+0200 (stredoeurópsky letný čas) Function
>   create_function() is deprecated  Type: PHP Deprecated Line: 57  File:
>   /home/qa015000/getogether/wp-content/themes/eventbuilder/widgets/td_video_widget.php

```
<?php        
class td_video_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'td_widget_video', 'description' => __( 'Insert your embedded code in here!', 'themesdojo') );
        parent::__construct('td_video_widget', __('ThemesDojo - Embedded Video', 'themesdojo'), $widget_ops);
        $this->alt_option_name = 'td_video_widget';

    }

    function form($instance) {

        $title = ( isset($instance['title']) && !empty($instance['title']) ) ? esc_attr($instance['title']) : '';
        $text = ( isset($instance['text']) && !empty($instance['text']) ) ? esc_attr($instance['text']) : '';

        ?>

        <label><?php _e('Title', 'themesdojo'); ?>: <input type="text" style="width:100%;" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('title')); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('title')); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" /></label>
        <label><?php _e('Text', 'themesdojo'); ?>: <textarea class="widefat" rows="16" cols="20" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('text')); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('text')); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr($text); ?></textarea></label>

        <?php

    }

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        return $new_instance;
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ){

        extract( $args );
        extract( $instance );

        if( $title )
            $title = $before_title.do_shortcode($title).$after_title;

        $text = do_shortcode( $text );
        $text = $title.'<div class="ut-video">'.$text.'</div>';

        echo "$before_widget
                $text
              $after_widget";
    }

}


add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'return register_widget("td_video_widget");' ) );

}
```

Comment: That's three lines of code, and none of them include `create_function`.

Comment: Sory, I update my question and this is all code from plugin and error log. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: There's still no `create_function` code in what you've shared. Search your code for `create_function`. Find it, and replace it.

Comment: U can use any callback

Comment: I added create_function.

Comment: `add_action( 'widgets_init', function() { return register_widget('td_video_widget'); } );` just replace your last line with that. However, since that appears to be a theme issue, you may want to update your theme - since they may have fixed this. If not, this will help until they do.